# Where are OpenGL textures stored on iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, textures

Where are textures stored in an OpenGL ES 2 iPad application? How can I determine the device capabilities for storing textures? I initially thought textures were stored in RAM, but the following code runs just fine instead of causing an overflow:

```
for(int i=0; i<3000; i++){ //Generate some textures and see when the space will run out
        GLuint texture;
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,  768, 1024, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
        NSLog(@"%i",glGetError());
}
```

Am I creating these textures the wrong way or is the iPad really capable of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textures are stored in *server space*. Thus, the driver probably optimizes the empty buffers and doesn't create them until you really need to put some data inside.

iPad is certainly not capable of storing 225GiB of textures. `:)`

EDIT: *`glAreTexturesResident` is deprecated already. I am not aware of any replacements for it*.

Answer (score 0):

For your question about determining capabilities try this:

```
    GLint maxNum;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &maxNum);
    GLint texturesMaxSize;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &texturesMaxSize);

    NSLog(@"Max textures: %d",aValue);
    NSLog(@"Max size: %d",texturesMaxSize);
```

If max size is 1024 then size is 1024 * 1024 and so on